# Mojave can't install octave/sagemath through conda

Tags: python3, anaconda, macos-mojave

When I try to install GNU-octave in conda using,

```
conda install octave
```

it gives me an error,

```
error conda.core.link:_execute(568): an error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::python.app-2-py37_9'.
```

and rolls back. After reading some GitHub page  I tried both deleting .app files in ~/anaconda3/bin and giving writing permission to ~/anaconda3/bin/conda and neither worked.